# equation - Missing { inserted

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am getting the error message Missing insert { when using the below mathematical equation. I have no spaces between the equation so not sure where is the issue. Thanks

```
\begin{equation}
MAE = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|{y}-{y^_j}|
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
RMSE = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}({y}-{y^_j})^2}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: `y^_J` ?  Is j as superscript or subscript?

Comment: What's `y^_{j}`supposed to produce?

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need `{}` around `y` nor around `y^j` or `y_j`.  Also, you shouldn't have two consecutive `equation` environments (it's not an error, but it doesn't look right - look into `gather` or `align`).

Comment: I am trying to represent the above equations. It is a subscript.

Comment: `\hat{y}_{j}` is the way to go.

Comment: @egreg your answer has got rid of the error message. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: One more thing no one has mentioned, you want to write, e.g., `\mathrm{RMSE}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commath` package is for `abs`use (matter of tastes, irrelevant).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{commath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    MAE = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\abs{y_j - \hat{y}_j}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    RMSE = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n (y_j - \hat{y}_j)^2}
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: please don't recommend commath, it is completely broken

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the advice. Is there another package that includes \abs and \norm?

Comment: mathtools would let you do `\newcommand*\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand*\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}`  (examples copied from `texdoc mathtools`)